# Hyperlink mail body issue with Lotus Traveler app on Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, lotus

I try to add some hyperlinks in mail body when I create my intent but they don't appears in the previsualisation and mail sent.
Also, I set the mime type with "text/html" and I used EXTRA_TEXT static.

This is my code :

```
                String text = "";
            text += "<html><body>";
            text += "<a href=\"" + CallAPI.mBaseUrl +
                    "/uploads/media/default/0001/01/021ffb272477a45c032c178de0160e352134f8dd.png" + "\">" + "test" + "</a>";
            text += "</body></html>";
            Log.d("FragmentFicheProduit", text);
            Utils.openApplication(rootView.getContext(), "com.lotus.sync.traveler", getResources().getString(R.string.information_nom_produit) + " " + produit.getNom_produit(), text, null);

   public static void openApplication(final Context context, String packageN, String subject, String text, ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/html");
    if (i != null) {
        if (subject != null)
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if (text != null)

            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text));
        if (contactArrayList != null) {
            String[] tmp = new String[contactArrayList.size()];
            for (int y = 0; y < contactArrayList.size(); y++) {
                tmp[y] = contactArrayList.get(y).getEmailaddress1();
            }
            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tmp);
        }
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".traveler")) best = info;
        }
        if (best != null)
            i.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageN)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageN)));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I also tried to add EXTRA_HTML_TEXT with Html.fromHtml("...").toString() without succes.

Comment: Following the lot of links you get when searching for this topic this will only work if the receiving application "talks" html. I unfortunately cannot answer, if the traveler app can. Just one thought: You could try not to built complete html, but just parts of it. Instead of doing `<html><body><a href=''...` you could try just `<a href=''>text</a>`

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Finally it works on Outlook. However, I would like to know if using css style is currently possible on android webmail via intent.